# How to get the positive modulo between floating-point numbers

Tags: c++, modulo

I have a real number x and I want to get the number `(x mod 2*PI) = y`, where `y` is between 0 and `2*PI`.

I could do it with a loop and if `x` is negative I just keep adding `2*pi` until my number is in range of `[0,2*pi]` or if x is greater the `2*pi` I could just keep subtracting. However, I hope there is a more elegant way to do this.

I tried this:

```
fmod(-0.3434073,2*M_PI);
```

but this remains `-0.3434073`. Why and how can I get it working as I want it to?

Comment: Create a condition. If the input is negative, then 2*M_PI have to be added to it after.

Comment: Do you need it modulo twice the `double` representation of π, or twice modulo the mathematical number 2π? In the second case, it is much more complicated, look up `“argument reduction” or take a look for instance at http://port70.net/~nsz/musl/clang-2013-10-04/report-00117a.html . Even in the first case, repeatedly adding or subtracting will cause rounding errors to be larger than necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: Credits to Notinlist for answering faster.

In the C99 standard, section 7.12.10.1 has this to say:

*The fmod functions return the value x − ny, for some integer n such that, if y is nonzero, the result has the same sign as x and magnitude less than the magnitude of y. If y is zero, whether a domain error occurs or the fmod functions return zero is implementation- defined.*

Going by this, you need to add *y* if you want the proper sign.

All in all:

```
double fmod_positive(double x, double y){
    double tmp = fmod(x, y);
    return x < 0 ? tmp + y : tmp;
}
```