# What's the fastest method to trim a number between -PI and +PI in C?

Tags: c, while-loop

Say I have a high floating point number... 1345.23
I want to reduce it by 2*PI until it stays between -PI and +PI so I'd do:

```
#define PI  3.14159265358f
#define TWO_PI  6.28318530718f

float a = 1345.23f;
while (a > PI) a -= TWO_PI;
```

Do you know a fastest method?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/remainder/

Comment: Please use `fmod`. And please use `double`, never use `float` on today's computers unless there is a specific reason to. You don't use `char` just because `int` is too big, do you?

Comment: @WeatherVane `fmod` will truncate the number between `0` and `TWO_PI`, not `-PI` and `PI`.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish that depends on how you use it. It was a hint. Treat positive and negative numbers separately.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish In which case,  `fmod` and then `- TWO_PI` will do the trick.

Comment: @MicroVirus That will truncate the number between `-TWO_PI` and `0`. Perhaps you meant `- PI`?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Woops, yes, `- PI` :)

Comment: Won't work for negative numbers. try it with a=-6.29 - the answer becomes -3.1484...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157089/i-need-modulo-in-c

Comment: @Weather Vane, float or double... It depends on the chip you're programming for ;) "Today's computers" is a vague term, the difference between float and double is for many chips still really important!

Comment: @Rolf ツ yes thanks, was talking of PC, my "specific reason" was if you can't use `double`.

Comment: What? No there are many uses for float instead of double, particularly in computer graphics where most of the hardware works best on floats.

Comment: @jcoder: that's a "specific reason". In general code, there is none. Use the best type available. Note: the accpeted answer advises use of `double`. That's the natural compiler understanding of `1.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code you will enter in the loop just 1 time (you can delate it adding just a more `a -= TWO_PI`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI      3.14159265358f
#define TWO_PI  6.28318530718f

int main(void) {

    float a = 1345.23f;
    float b = 1345.23 - PI;
    int c = b/TWO_PI;

    a -= c*TWO_PI; 
    int i = 0;
    while (a > PI){
        a -= TWO_PI;
        printf("%d",i++);
    }

    printf("\na : %f",a);
}
```

OUTPUT:

> 0
>    a : 0.628314

While your code will do the cicle :

```
214 times
```

---

### BETTER CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI         3.14159265358f
#define TWO_PI     6.28318530718f
#define INV_TWO_PI 0.15915494309189533

int main(void) {

    double a = 1345.23;
    if(a > PI){

        double b = a - PI; // you get the distance between a and PI

        // int c = b/TWO_PI; // you get the integer part
        int c = b * INV_TWO_PI; // the same as above using multiplication

        a -= (c+1)*TWO_PI; // you just subtract c+1 times TWO_PI
                           // c+1 cause you want come in the range [-PI,PI]
    }
}
```

Comment: @adminXVII what change if I mixed the calculus? they just become unreadeble for who want to understand! You make a new answer just mixing my calculus..

Comment: @Bob__ Is multiplication faster then division with decimals too?

Comment: It was, now with smart compilers and even smarter FPU it's worth testing.

Comment: @Bob__ Thank's bob.. I googled and yes with actual compilers there isn't any difference (or almost). However I get your idea for improve my answer (If is not better, in the worst case is the same :) )

Comment: I accept this as the answer to my question because I have just tested it and is indeed the fastest solution among the many I already tried.

Comment: Please remove the `f` qualifiers in your "better" `double` solution, otherwise +1.

Comment: The "better" method fails for negative values.  It also loses all significance for small values of `a`,  Fails for large values of `a` due to `int` overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Not the fastest, but the shortest code:
  y = asin(sin(a));

Comment: The question is: "Do you know a fastest method?" not "Do you know a shortest method?" :)

Comment: Nice try ;). [It may be less precise then expected](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/)...

Comment: `asin()` returns a number in the interval [−π /2, +π /2] and does not met OP's posted goal.  [`remquof(x, pi2, &n);`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37492571/2410359) is shorter code than `asin(sin(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code has to do with phase wrapping in *radians*, so that values between `PI` and `TWO_PI` can map between `-PI` and `0.0` a simple and fast solution would be:

```
double a = 1345.23;
double b = TWO_PI;
double c = (fmod(a,b) > PI ? fmod(a,b) - b  : fmod(a,b));
```

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer

To *quickly* reduce between `-PI` and `PI`, simply use `remquof()`;

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float reduce_radian(float x) {
  static const float pi2 = 6.283185307179586476925286766559f;
  int n;
  return remquof(x, pi2, &n);
}

int main(void) {
  printf("x % .10e\ty % .10e\n", 1e-30, reduce_radian(1e-30));
  for (float x = 0.0f; x <= 4.0f; x += 1.0f) {
    printf("x % .10f\ty % .10f\n", -x, reduce_radian(-x));
    printf("x % .10f\ty % .10f\n", x, reduce_radian(x));
  }
}
```

Output

```
x  1.0000000000e-30 y  1.0000000032e-30
x -0.0000000000 y -0.0000000000
x  0.0000000000 y  0.0000000000
x -1.0000000000 y -1.0000000000
x  1.0000000000 y  1.0000000000
x -2.0000000000 y -2.0000000000
x  2.0000000000 y  2.0000000000
x -3.0000000000 y -3.0000000000
x  3.0000000000 y  3.0000000000
x -4.0000000000 y  2.2831854820
x  4.0000000000 y -2.2831854820
```

To understand why this is not the best *precise* answer, is a deep subject.

See [K.C. Ng's "ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit"](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf)